# HttpClient response only one line of XML

Tags: java, android, apache, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to fetch an XML file and I'm having issues getting the entire document returned (it only returns one line of the XML file). So:

```
DefaultHttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicResponseHandler r = new BasicResponseHandler();

String s = null;
try
{
    s = c.execute(new HttpGet("http://localhost/activity.xml"), r);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i(TAG, s);
```

The resulting string is always just `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Is there something I need to do to tell HttpClient to load the entire file or process newlines or something? XML is super simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <group-id type="integer">2187</group-id>
    <icon type="integer">2</icon>
    <name>Android</name>
    <overview>android app</overview>
    <permalink>codebase</permalink>
    <start-page>tickets</start-page>
    <status>active</status>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a `BasicResponseHandler` as the response handler, the result of `execute` should be the entire response body.

If you are getting just one line, my theory is that that is all that the server is sending.

Take a look at the server logs to see if an exception is being thrown while it is generating the response body.  (If you are using a JSP to do the rendering for example, an exception thrown cannot be reported back to the client via the HTTP status code.  Instead the client will see a 200 response with a truncated body.)

Comment: Nothing in the logs. It's just a static XML file at the moment. I can point to the URL in the browser and it displays just fine. Very confused as it was working a few days ago.

Comment: I just rebooted IntelliJ and the Emulator and now it's loading the entire body. I guess it was something wrong with my AVD. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String page = sb.toString();
            Log.d("Join", page);
```

And if you want to get just xml data, you'd better extend DefaultHandler. And use a parser like SAXParser ,XMLReader.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am using DefaultHandler and SAX I was just writing this to figure out why my XML wasn't fully loading.

Comment: Then you should use this format as <attr_name data="some data"/>
see this http://www.google.co.kr/ig/api?weather=NY