# Http Connection from Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, java-server

I am trying to connect from java android program to a http website.
I am trying this code. But apparently, the code does not go pass the "client.execute()" statement.
I have commented a return statement after execute and it does not go passed that.
Am i missing something?

I had tried pretty the same code and it didnt work so i did copy the exact same code form Newboston and it still doesn't work.

(Code from Newboston.)

Thank you in advance.

```
public class GetMethodEx {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in=null;
    String data=null;

    try{
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website=new URI("http://www.mybringback.com");
        HttpGet request=new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);

        HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);

    //  if(data==null)
    //      return "bfdvhf";

        in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
        String l="";
        String nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while((l=in.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
            return "hfeuhfuie";

        }
        in.close();
        data=sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally{
        if(in!=null)
        {
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: How do you call getInternetData()? From an Activity? 
Just an advice: any http request should run outsite a Thread UI. Use an AsyncTask.

Comment: Hey,
Yeah I'm calling from activity only. But even if i call from an activity , it should work just fine right?
I have the code ready with me, but this one statement is causing a problem.

Comment: Put breakpoints on this line, `in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));` and on e.printStackTrace in your catch.  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942075/httpclient-response-only-one-line-of-xml

Comment: @JS_VIPER On Android Honeycomb or higher you should use another thread to do an HTTP request. Take a look on AsyncTask docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your app crashes/throws exception on `execute()`? If so, you most likely getting [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) exception - it is related to networking on UI thread (i.e trying to network directly in your Activity class). You have to separate networking and run this code asynchrously (usually using `IntentService` or `AsyncTask`).

See [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) for more information.

BTW: next time always post your logcat output with your question

Comment: No the app does not crash and i have put a exception for this and its just prints the exception.

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie to this field.